# how to protect the db username and password in tomcat server.xml

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7

i have a spring application and i am deploying it on tomcat7. for connection i configured jndi in server.xml
here is my xml file.

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
             global="jdbc/MCDataSource"
            initialSize="20" maxAge="7200000" maxIdle="20" maxTotal="75"
            maxWaitMillis="15000" name="jdbc/MCDataSource" password="AppDB"
            testOnBorrow="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.19.8.159:1521/OIM.itba.gov.in" username="AppDB"
            validationQuery="select 1" />
```

here i need some suggestions that how can i protect my username,password in production environment .
i have seen so many suggestion that we can do encryption but some suggestions are like encryption is not the best way to protect because it can be decrypt it easily.one this i know that i should not pass the plan text like this here. so i just want to know what is the best approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add `digest` attribute on your `<Realm>` element in server.xml with value `md5`.

2) Go to your `CATALINA_HOME` and run below command

```
java -cp lib/catalina.jar:bin/tomcat-juli.jar org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase -a md5 <YOUR_PASSWORD>
```

You will get `<YOUR_PASSWORD>:<ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD>`

3) Replace value of user's `password` attribute in your tomcat-users.xml to `<ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD>`

4) Restart tomcat